# How to can I run my xcode project on Iphone or Ipad?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a project that was made in Xcode7 .
I want to run it (export the ipa and install it) on an iPhone 4 or iPad.
When navigating to Window->Devices, I could not see any of my devices.

Can someone advice on what to do? 
Thank you!

Comment: when you connect your device to your system, the device is showing in your system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you will need to archive the ipa, to do this set the device to `iOS Device`

[image]

2. Archive the ipa using `Product -> Archive`

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Install ipa on your device using test flight, to do this upload your ipa using application loader application, [find out more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35)

Comment: What type of archiev should I do?I've seend many option like adhoc

Answer (score 0):

Go to fullscreen mode. See the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Check the device cable.

Comment: Can you see your iphone in eg iTunes?

Comment: When I am connecting the devices are charging

Comment: Yes. Is your device jail break one?

Comment: What is the OS version? Could be your Xcode updated one and device has low OS. BTW do you have apple license?

Comment: yes I have it.I have Ipad air with the version IOS 9.2.1,On deployment target I choose IOS 9.2

Comment: You need apple developer license as well.

Comment: I have one.I could archieve the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103174/discussion-between-techbee-and-carmen-mitru).

Answer (score 0):

you have to register the device on the devices section on your developer account .